# ROS2_Control question

Tags: ros2-control, diff-drive-controller, ros2-controllers

Can anyone clarify the units of diff_drive_controller, Command interfaces in velocity are in rad/sec ? and state interfaces for encoders are rotations ? and velocity is again rad/sec ?

Also is there a way in galactic distro under ros2_control to mention the gear reduction so the cmd_vels are generated accordingly or is it going to be part of write function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Galactic is EOL and doesn't receive any updates any more. Please upgrade to a more recent distro.

You are right. The command interfaces is of velocity type (angular speed of the wheels). For odometry calculations, you can use it `open_loop` (without any sensors), or with sensors: Depending on the parameter `position_feedback` the state interface has to be of type position or velocity.

For more details check the [documentation](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/diff_drive_controller/doc/userdoc.html)